# mysqli flag fields (working code)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is a follow-on post from [What do bit flags in mysqli mean using fetch_field_direct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437650/what-do-bit-flags-in-mysqli-mean-using-fetch-field-direct). Here is an example of a script that will process a table in a database specified in the url by adding ?tablename=
The field codes that are displayed when the user mouse-overs the table headings do not reflect the attributes of the fields in the table (these codes come from suggestions in http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php#101828).
The field flags output do not describe the fields in the table. What are the correct meanings for the field flags?

```
<?php
/*----- Store username, password and name of database in variables
        Log in to database using mysqli */
    $user="username";
    $pass="password";
    $dbname="databaseName";

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "$user", "$pass", "$dbname");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/*----- Gets the table name from the URI 
        If no table is selected, choose a default table. */
if (isset($_GET['tablename'])){ 
    $tablename = $_GET['tablename'];
}
else {
    $tablename = "defaultTable";
}
$query="SELECT * FROM ".$tablename;
/*----- Query additions */
if (isset($_GET['id'])){    
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query.=" WHERE ".$tablename."_id=".$id;
}

if ($query != "") {
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

    //First, find the number of fields returned in the query and set fieldCount to 0
    $numFields=$result->field_count;
    $numRows=$result->num_rows;
    $fieldCount=0;

    //If the number of rows or the number of fields equals zero, add an error message

    $errorText = "";
    if ($numFields == "0") {
        $errorText .= "No fields in this table.";
    }
    if ($numRows == "0") {
        $errorText .= "Query did not return any results.";
    }

    //Next, store the field names in an array
    do{
        $field[$fieldCount] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $fieldCount);
        $fieldname[]=$field[$fieldCount]->name;
        $fieldlength[]=$field[$fieldCount]->length;
        $fieldflags[]=$field[$fieldCount]->flags;
        $fieldCount++;
    }
    while ($numFields>$fieldCount);

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}

        ?> 
        <table >
            <thead>
            <?php
                $fieldCount=0;
                while ($fieldCount<$numFields)
                {
                    $flag = decbin($fieldflags[$fieldCount]);
                    /* str_pad(string, length of desired string, what to pad with, 0 for right or 1 for left or 2 for both) */
                    $flag = str_pad($flag,'19','0','0');
                    echo "<th title=\"";
                    echo $flag ."\n";
                    if ($flag[0] == "1" ) {echo "NOT NULL \n";}
                    if ($flag[1] == "1" ) {echo "PRIMARY KEY \n";}
                    if ($flag[2] == "1" ) {echo "UNIQUE KEY \n";}
                    if ($flag[3] == "1" ) {echo "MULTIPLE KEY \n";}
                    if ($flag[4] == "1" ) {echo "BLOB \n";}
                    if ($flag[5] == "1" ) {echo "UNSIGNED \n";}
                    if ($flag[6] == "1" ) {echo "ZEROFILL \n";}
                    if ($flag[7] == "1" ) {echo "BINARY \n";}
                    if ($flag[8] == "1" ) {echo "ENUM \n";}
                    if ($flag[9] == "1" ) {echo "AUTO INCREMENT \n";}
                    if ($flag[10] == "1" ) {echo "TIMESTAMP \n";}
                    if ($flag[11] == "1" ) {echo "SET \n";}
                    if ($flag[12] == "1" ) {echo " \n";}
                    if ($flag[13] == "1" ) {echo " \n";}
                    if ($flag[14] == "1" ) {echo "PART KEY \n";}
                    if ($flag[15] == "1" ) {echo "GROUP FLAG \n";}
                    if ($flag[16] == "1" ) {echo "NUM FLAG     \n";}
                    if ($flag[17] == "1" ) {echo "UNIQUE FLAG    \n";}
                    if ($flag[18] == "1" ) {echo " \n";}

                    echo "\">".ucfirst(str_replace($tablename."_","",$fieldname[$fieldCount])) ."</th>";
                    $fieldCount++;
                }
            ?>
            <td></td>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php
            $rowCounter = 0;
            $fieldCount=0;
            while($rowCounter < $numRows){
                echo "

                <form name=\"update-".$rows[$rowCounter][0]."\"
                      id=\"update-".$rows[$rowCounter][0]."\"
                      method=\"post\" >
                <tr id=\"update-".$rows[$rowCounter][0]."\">
                ";

                while($fieldCount < $numFields){
                    echo"
                        <td><input size=\"$fieldlength[$fieldCount]\" maxlength=\"$fieldlength[$fieldCount]\" value=\"".$rows[$rowCounter][$fieldCount]."\" /></td>
                    ";
                    $fieldCount++;
                }
                $fieldCount=0;
                echo"
                <td>
                <a href=\"thispage.php?tablename=".$tablename."&id=".$rows[$rowCounter][0]."\" >view</a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </form>";
                $rowCounter++;
            }
            $rowCounter=0;
    echo "<tbody>
        </table>";
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Gumbo - ... by design :-!

Answer (score 1):

Those flags are briefly explained in the [C API Data Structures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-data-structures.html) chapter of the MySQL manual:

```
Flag Value             Flag Description
NOT_NULL_FLAG          Field can't be NULL
PRI_KEY_FLAG           Field is part of a primary key
UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG        Field is part of a unique key
MULTIPLE_KEY_FLAG      Field is part of a nonunique key
UNSIGNED_FLAG          Field has the UNSIGNED attribute
ZEROFILL_FLAG          Field has the ZEROFILL attribute
BINARY_FLAG            Field has the BINARY attribute
AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG    Field has the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute
ENUM_FLAG              Field is an ENUM (deprecated)
SET_FLAG               Field is a SET (deprecated)
BLOB_FLAG              Field is a BLOB or TEXT (deprecated)
TIMESTAMP_FLAG         Field is a TIMESTAMP (deprecated)
NUM_FLAG               Field is numeric; see additional notes following table
NO_DEFAULT_VALUE_FLAG  Field has no default value; see additional notes following table
```

They're linked to equivalent PHP constants as described in the [Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php) section of the Mysqli manual.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient but this might help somebody else.  I think the problem is that the indices in the $flag array are read in reverse order - they should run from 18 to 0 to get the correct results.  Or the descriptors should be inverted.