# Convert mysql_field_flags to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to convert a module from mysql to mysqli. At one point the module uses the function:

```
mysql_field_flags($fields,$n)
```

This returns a string of flags like: "not_null", "primary_key", "unique_key", etc..

What is the mysqli function that returns the same? Because

```
mysqli_fetch_field_direct($fields,$n)->flags
```

returns only an integer and not the field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it does return an integer, which is a *bitmask* of flags. You'd use this with the [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php) (those named `*_FLAG`):

```
$flags = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($fields, $n)->flags;
if ($flags & MYSQLI_NOT_NULL_FLAG) {
    echo 'Field has NOT NULL';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! However, for some reason the integer results I get from 

mysqli_fetch_field_direct($fields,$n)->flags

do not seem to correspond to the predefined constants. Integers I get for example are 0, 32768 or 9377. These don't seem like the right integers?

Comment: It's a *bitmask* which you need to *bitwise* compare to the constants, as shown. The single integer corresponds to *several flags at once* and needs to be `&`-compared to see if it contains one specific flag or not.

Comment: this is best solution, u must need to know the constant value of 32768 which is NUM_FLAG... it just an example.. u can create a custom array or any thing else at once.. @BasVerhaar

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom function, i hope this will help you.

```
/**
* Get column data type in mysqli
**/

function getColumnDataType($info){

    // default data types
    $mysql_data_type_hash = array(
    1=>'tinyint',
    2=>'smallint',
    3=>'int',
    4=>'float',
    5=>'double',
    7=>'timestamp',
    8=>'bigint',
    9=>'mediumint',
    10=>'date',
    11=>'time',
    12=>'datetime',
    13=>'year',
    16=>'bit',
    //252 is currently mapped to all text and blob types (MySQL 5.0.51a)
    253=>'varchar',
    254=>'char',
    246=>'decimal'
    );


    foreach ($mysql_data_type_hash as $key => $value) {
        if($key == $info->type){
            echo $value;
        }
    }

    if ($info->flags & MYSQLI_AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG) {
        echo ' AUTO_INCREMENT';
    }

    if ($info->flags & MYSQLI_NOT_NULL_FLAG) {
        echo ' NOT NULL';
    }

    if ($info->flags & MYSQLI_NUM_FLAG) {
        echo ' NUMERIC';
    }

    if ($info->flags & MYSQLI_UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG) {
        echo ' UNIQUE INDEX';
    }
}
```

**How can you use it?**

For suppose your query is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM mytable");
$finfo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, 0); // checking field 1

// call the function 
$type = getColumnDataType($finfo); 
echo $type; // int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL NUMERIC
```

Note that, my ist field is auto increment so i get this in result:

```
int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL NUMERIC
```

**Side Note:**

For other flags you can follow the these links:

**[MYSQLI CONSTANTS](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php)**

[Other Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437650/what-do-bit-flags-in-mysqli-mean-using-fetch-field-direct)